# 3 tier architecture ado.net application

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, ado.net

I would like to develop a student management system with repository pattern using ado.net (no EF or MVC).

I decided to create the model (business objects) and interfaces as one project "StudentModel". Implementing the interfaces to fetch data from DB as one project "StudentImpl" and the third will be the web application which will call the implementations and populate the views.

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="Dbconnection"
   connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=studentdb ; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

My Model

```
 public class Student
 {
   public int StudentID { get; set; }
   public string StudentName { get; set; }
 }
```

My Repository

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T Create(T entity);
    T Update(T entity);
    T Delete(T entity);
    IList<T> FindAll();
}
```

My Implementation

```
public class StudentRepository:IRepository<Student>
{
    SqlConnection aConnection;
    public StudentRepository(string ConnectionString)
    {
         aConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    }

    public Student Create(Student entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Student Update(Student entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Student Delete(Student entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IList<Student> FindAll()
    {
        IList<Student> Students = new List<Student>();
        using(aConnection)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT studentID,StudentName FROM Student", aConnection);
            aConnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Student aStudent = new Student();
                aStudent.StudentID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["StudentID"]);
                aStudent.StudentName = rdr["StudentName"].ToString();
                Students.Add(aStudent);
            }
            return Students;
        }
    }
```

And my code behind

```
string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString;
IRepository<Student> aStudent = new StudentRepository(ConString);
IList<Student> Students=aStudent.FindAll();
```

What would be the best place to pass the connection string to the implementation and how can I improve this code further?

Please give your comments on my design and help me to improve.

Edit:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dbconnection"].ToString();
        IStudent aStudent = new StudentRepository(ConString);
        IList<StudentModel.Student> students= aStudent.FindAll();
        GvStudent.DataSource = students;
        GvStudent.DataBind();

    }

    protected void GvStudent_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Row.RowType.Equals(DataControlRowType.DataRow)) return;
        HyperLink lnkName = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("lnkName");
        string id = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblID")).Text;
        lnkName.NavigateUrl = "~/Edit.aspx?q=" + id;
    }

    protected void GvStudent_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GvStudent.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        string ConString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dbconnection"].ToString();
        IStudent aStudent = new StudentRepository(ConString);
        IList<StudentModel.Student> students = aStudent.FindAll();
        GvStudent.DataSource = students;
        GvStudent.DataBind();

    }

    protected void export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string formatstring = default(string);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    string FileName = "Samepl.xls";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
    Response.Charset = "";
    EnableViewState = false;
    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GvStudent.AllowPaging = false;
    GvStudent.RenderControl(htw);
    string value = sw.ToString();
    GvStudent.AllowPaging = true;
    Response.Write(formatstring + value);
    Response.End();
    }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {

    }
}

    <asp:GridView ID="GvStudent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GvStudent_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="2" OnPageIndexChanging="GvStudent_PageIndexChanging" PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast">
    <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Student Name
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("StudentName") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                           </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Student ID
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("StudentID") %>' ></asp:Label>
                           </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: If someone can guide me to achieve the same through MVC and EF, it would be great.

Answer (score 7):

The only thing I'd say about your repository, is that `FindAll` shouldn't return an `IList<T>`, but an `IEnumerable<T>`. And you're probably missing a method like `GetById` that returns only a single record - right now the only way to fetch a single student is... to fetch them all and then filter in memory. The database backend is better at this, you will want LINQ-to-SQL to pick up the criteria and translate a `WHERE` clause on the server.

You're missing a *unit of work*. Each repository owns its own connection to the database, which means if you have a business requirement to `Delete` a `Student` and everything associated to it, you're going to have to do it with as many connections as you have tables affected.

One way to have a *unit of work* is to use Entity Framework (that would mootinate your repositories); another way is to roll your own: instead of having code-behind that depends on repositories, you have code-behind that depends on a *unit-of-work*:

```
string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString;
IUnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork(ConString);
IList<Student> Students = uow.Students.FindAll();
```

In other words, *push* the responsibility of owning the connection outside of your repositories - let the repositories depend on a connection instead, and let the unit of work pass it down to each repository. Doing this will enable deleting/inserting/updating data from multiple repositories within a transaction which can be rolled back if things go wrong halfway through.

---

Achieving the same thing with EF is simpler: **EF already implements repositories and unit-of-work for you**, and `SaveChanges` operates like a `Commit` - you can `Rollback` the changes by simply disposing the `DbContext` before `SaveChanges` is called.

Comment: Thanks! If I need to move the connection string to a common place, so that the connection string is initialised only once, how could I do that? Masterpage code behind or App code or in Global asax?

Comment: Putting it in the master page will initialize it once *per request* - putting it in global.asax will initialize it once *in the app's lifetime*. You decide ;)

Comment: I need it to be there in global.asax but how can I pass it from global.asax to my implementation while I access any method like FindALL() ?

Comment: Also I believe, I've implemented Repository pattern through Interfaces and Dependency Injection through StudentRepository constructor. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC you could make the global setting a constructor argument for your controllers. I'd have to relook at the chapter about ASP.NET in *Dependency Injection in .NET* to see how DI works with ASP.NET, but if I remember correctly your *composition root* is at the page level and you have to work around that (I don't think you can control a page's constructor parameters), so you're probably better off composing your dependencies in the master page's code-behind.

Comment: Sorry if this is back-and-forth.. I don't do ASP.NET very often ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14651/discussion-between-tech-jerk-and-mats-mug).

Answer (score 5):

Aside from Mat's comments there are a few minor things:

- Parameters are *lowerCamelCase* so `ConnectionString` becomes `connectionString`.
- In your SQL query you use `studentID` and in the reader you use `StudentID`.
- Local variables are *lowerCamelCase* so `Students` becomes `students`.

Aside from that there is not much code to review.

Comment: Thanks! If I need to move the connection string to a common place, so that the connection string is initialised only once, how could I do that? Masterpage code behind or App code or in Global asax?

Comment: Use the `App.Config` or `Web.Config` configuration file where you can add your own keys under `<AppSettings>`. Afterwards you can use them with `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"]`

Comment: Also I believe, I've implemented Repository pattern through Interfaces and Dependency Injection through StudentRepository constructor. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: W.r.t to Mat's comment, I need it to be there in global.asax but how can I pass it from global.asax to my implementation while I access any method like FindALL()